# Address in mailbox given [API base URL: ] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

config/mail.php

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => '',
    'port' => '',
    'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
    'encryption' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

Usercontroller.php

```
public function welcome_email_confirmation($user)
{
    $data['first_name'] = $user->first_name;
    $data['email'] = $user->email;
    $data['token'] = str_random(100); // Generate random string values - limit 100
    $data['type'] = 'welcome';
    $data['url'] = url().'/';
    $data['locale']       = App::getLocale();

    $password_resets = new PasswordResets;

    $password_resets->email      = $user->email;
    $password_resets->token      = $data['token'];
    $password_resets->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $password_resets->save();
    $data['subject'] = trans('messages.email.confirm_email_address');
    Mail::send('emails.email_confirm', $data, function($message) use($data){
     $message->to($data['email'], $data['first_name'])->subject
        ($data['subject']);
    });

    return true;
}
```

In this code I am simply doing sign up but I have got this error when click on sign up button `Address in mailbox given [API base URL: ] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.`. How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

in some similar situations I realized that the error was fired for sender email address and not destination email address.
In your config/mail.php you are not setting sender email credentials.

Regards.

Comment: I had fill all the credential but problem is same @FaridSilva

Comment: According to a similar issue in GitHub check the following reply
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/382